# New answer to old question about Google Sheets/Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-calendar-recurring-events

I found this [old question about synchronizing Google Sheets and Google Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497977/google-calendar-sync-with-google-spreadsheet) and tried to download the template and then edit it accordingly.

When I try to run the script it prompts this error **ReferenceError: calenderId is not defined**.

Since I can only see one line, 9, where to to enter the calendarId I can not make the script work.

Did I miss a line in my [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-KTXd6NM58MB7-ENzHo5TfO3MXcNx58Mp42mkqwkqSU/edit?usp=sharing)? I am aware that I need to write my cal-id in line 9.

```
// Script to synchronize a calendar to a spreadsheet and vice versa.
//
// See https://github.com/Davepar/gcalendarsync for instructions on setting this up.
//

// Set this value to match your calendar!!!
// Calendar ID can be found in the "Calendar Address" section of the Calendar Settings.
//var calendarId = '<your-calendar-id>@group.calendar.google.com';
var calendarId = 'Her er min kalender-adresse, naturligvis';

// Set the beginning and end dates that should be synced. beginDate can be set to Date() to use
// today. The numbers are year, month, date, where month is 0 for Jan through 11 for Dec.
var beginDate = new Date(1970, 0, 1);  // Default to Jan 1, 1970
var endDate = new Date(2500, 0, 1);  // Default to Jan 1, 2500


// Date format to use in the spreadsheet.
var dateFormat = 'M/d/yyyy H:mm';

var titleRowMap = {
  'title': 'Title',
  'description': 'Description',
  'location': 'Location',
  'starttime': 'Start Time',
  'endtime': 'End Time',
  'guests': 'Guests',
  'color': 'Color',
  'id': 'Id'
};
var titleRowKeys = ['title', 'description', 'location', 'starttime', 'endtime', 'guests', 'color', 'id'];
var requiredFields = ['id', 'title', 'starttime', 'endtime'];

// This controls whether email invites are sent to guests when the event is created in the
// calendar. Note that any changes to the event will cause email invites to be resent.
var SEND_EMAIL_INVITES = false;

// Setting this to true will silently skip rows that have a blank start and end time
// instead of popping up an error dialog.
var SKIP_BLANK_ROWS = false;

// Updating too many events in a short time period triggers an error. These values
// were successfully used for deleting and adding 240 events. Values in milliseconds.
var THROTTLE_SLEEP_TIME = 200;
var MAX_RUN_TIME = 5.75 * 60 * 1000;

// Special flag value. Don't change.
var EVENT_DIFFS_WITH_GUESTS = 999;

// Adds the custom menu to the active spreadsheet.
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [
    {
      name: "Update from Calendar",
      functionName: "syncFromCalendar"
    }, {
      name: "Update to Calendar",
      functionName: "syncToCalendar"
    }
  ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu('Calendar Sync', menuEntries);
}

// Creates a mapping array between spreadsheet column and event field name
function createIdxMap(row) {
  var idxMap = [];
  for (var idx = 0; idx < row.length; idx++) {
    var fieldFromHdr = row[idx];
    for (var titleKey in titleRowMap) {
      if (titleRowMap[titleKey] == fieldFromHdr) {
        idxMap.push(titleKey);
        break;
      }
    }
    if (idxMap.length <= idx) {
      // Header field not in map, so add null
      idxMap.push(null);
    }
  }
  return idxMap;
}

// Converts a spreadsheet row into an object containing event-related fields
function reformatEvent(row, idxMap, keysToAdd) {
  var reformatted = row.reduce(function(event, value, idx) {
    if (idxMap[idx] != null) {
      event[idxMap[idx]] = value;
    }
    return event;
  }, {});
  for (var k in keysToAdd) {
    reformatted[keysToAdd[k]] = '';
  }
  return reformatted;
}

// Converts a calendar event to a psuedo-sheet event.
function convertCalEvent(calEvent) {
  convertedEvent = {
    'id': calEvent.getId(),
    'title': calEvent.getTitle(),
    'description': calEvent.getDescription(),
    'location': calEvent.getLocation(),
    'guests': calEvent.getGuestList().map(function(x) {return x.getEmail();}).join(','),
    'color': calEvent.getColor()
  };
  if (calEvent.isAllDayEvent()) {
    convertedEvent.starttime = calEvent.getAllDayStartDate();
    var endtime = calEvent.getAllDayEndDate();
    if (endtime - convertedEvent.starttime === 24 * 3600 * 1000) {
      convertedEvent.endtime = '';
    } else {
      convertedEvent.endtime = endtime;
      if (endtime.getHours() === 0 && endtime.getMinutes() == 0) {
        convertedEvent.endtime.setSeconds(endtime.getSeconds() - 1);
      }
    }
  } else {
    convertedEvent.starttime = calEvent.getStartTime();
    convertedEvent.endtime = calEvent.getEndTime();
  }
  return convertedEvent;
}

// Converts calendar event into spreadsheet data row
function calEventToSheet(calEvent, idxMap, dataRow) {
  convertedEvent = convertCalEvent(calEvent);

  for (var idx = 0; idx < idxMap.length; idx++) {
    if (idxMap[idx] !== null) {
      dataRow[idx] = convertedEvent[idxMap[idx]];
    }
  }
}

// Returns empty string or time in milliseconds for Date object
function getEndTime(ev) {
  return ev.endtime === '' ? '' : ev.endtime.getTime();
}

// Determines the number of field differences between a calendar event and
// a spreadsheet event
function eventDifferences(convertedCalEvent, sev) {
  var eventDiffs = 0 + (convertedCalEvent.title !== sev.title) +
    (convertedCalEvent.description !== sev.description) +
    (convertedCalEvent.location !== sev.location) +
    (convertedCalEvent.starttime.toString() !== sev.starttime.toString()) +
    (getEndTime(convertedCalEvent) !== getEndTime(sev)) +
    (convertedCalEvent.guests !== sev.guests) +
    (convertedCalEvent.color !== ('' + sev.color));
  if (eventDiffs > 0 && convertedCalEvent.guests) {
    // Use a special flag value if an event changed, but it has guests.
    eventDiffs = EVENT_DIFFS_WITH_GUESTS;
  }
  return eventDiffs;
}

// Determine whether required fields are missing
function areRequiredFieldsMissing(idxMap) {
  return requiredFields.some(function(val) {
    return idxMap.indexOf(val) < 0;
  });
}

// Returns list of fields that aren't in spreadsheet
function missingFields(idxMap) {
  return titleRowKeys.filter(function(val) {
    return idxMap.indexOf(val) < 0;
  });
}

// Set up formats and hide ID column for empty spreadsheet
function setUpSheet(sheet, fieldKeys) {
  sheet.getRange(1, fieldKeys.indexOf('starttime') + 1, 999).setNumberFormat(dateFormat);
  sheet.getRange(1, fieldKeys.indexOf('endtime') + 1, 999).setNumberFormat(dateFormat);
  sheet.hideColumns(fieldKeys.indexOf('id') + 1);
}

// Display error alert
function errorAlert(msg, evt, ridx) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  if (evt) {
    ui.alert('Skipping row: ' + msg + ' in event "' + evt.title + '", row ' + (ridx + 1));
  } else {
    ui.alert(msg);
  }
}

// Updates a calendar event from a sheet event.
function updateEvent(calEvent, convertedCalEvent, sheetEvent){
  var numChanges = 0;
  sheetEvent.sendInvites = SEND_EMAIL_INVITES;
  if (convertedCalEvent.starttime.toString() !== sheetEvent.starttime.toString() ||
      getEndTime(convertedCalEvent) !== getEndTime(sheetEvent)) {
    if (sheetEvent.endtime === '') {
      calEvent.setAllDayDate(sheetEvent.starttime);
    } else {
      calEvent.setTime(sheetEvent.starttime, sheetEvent.endtime);
    }
    numChanges++;
  }
  if (convertedCalEvent.title !== sheetEvent.title) {
    calEvent.setTitle(sheetEvent.title);
    numChanges++;
  }
  if (convertedCalEvent.description !== sheetEvent.description) {
    calEvent.setDescription(sheetEvent.description);
    numChanges++;
  }
  if (convertedCalEvent.location !== sheetEvent.location) {
    calEvent.setLocation(sheetEvent.location);
    numChanges++;
  }
  if (convertedCalEvent.color !== ('' + sheetEvent.color)) {
    if (sheetEvent.color > 0 && sheetEvent.color < 12) {
      calEvent.setColor('' + sheetEvent.color);
      numChanges++;
    }
  }
  if (convertedCalEvent.guests !== sheetEvent.guests) {
    var guestCal = calEvent.getGuestList().map(function (x) {
      return {
        email: x.getEmail(),
        added: false
      };
    });
    var sheetGuests = sheetEvent.guests || '';
    var guests = sheetGuests.split(',').map(function (x) {
      return x ? x.trim() : '';
    });
    // Check guests that are already invited.
    for (var gIx = 0; gIx < guestCal.length; gIx++) {
      var index = guests.indexOf(guestCal[gIx].email);
      if (index >= 0) {
        guestCal[gIx].added = true;
        guests.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
    guests.forEach(function (guest) {
      if (guest) {
        calEvent.addGuest(guest);
        numChanges++;
      }
    });
    guestCal.forEach(function (guest) {
      if (!guest.added) {
        calEvent.removeGuest(guest.email);
        numChanges++;
      }
    });
  }
  // Throttle updates.
  Utilities.sleep(THROTTLE_SLEEP_TIME * numChanges);
  return numChanges;
}

// Synchronize from calendar to spreadsheet.
function syncFromCalendar() {
  console.info('Starting sync from calendar');
  // Get calendar and events
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var calEvents = calendar.getEvents(beginDate, endDate);

  // Get spreadsheet and data
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  var eventFound = new Array(data.length);

  // Check if spreadsheet is empty and add a title row
  var titleRow = [];
  for (var idx = 0; idx < titleRowKeys.length; idx++) {
    titleRow.push(titleRowMap[titleRowKeys[idx]]);
  }
  if (data.length < 1) {
    data.push(titleRow);
    range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length);
    range.setValues(data);
    setUpSheet(sheet, titleRowKeys);
  }

  if (data.length == 1 && data[0].length == 1 && data[0][0] === '') {
    data[0] = titleRow;
    range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length);
    range.setValues(data);
    setUpSheet(sheet, titleRowKeys);
  }

  // Map spreadsheet headers to indices
  var idxMap = createIdxMap(data[0]);
  var idIdx = idxMap.indexOf('id');

  // Verify header has all required fields
  if (areRequiredFieldsMissing(idxMap)) {
    var reqFieldNames = requiredFields.map(function(x) {return titleRowMap[x];}).join(', ');
    errorAlert('Spreadsheet must have ' + reqFieldNames + ' columns');
    return;
  }

  // Array of IDs in the spreadsheet
  var sheetEventIds = data.slice(1).map(function(row) {return row[idIdx];});

  // Loop through calendar events
  for (var cidx = 0; cidx < calEvents.length; cidx++) {
    var calEvent = calEvents[cidx];
    var calEventId = calEvent.getId();

    var ridx = sheetEventIds.indexOf(calEventId) + 1;
    if (ridx < 1) {
      // Event not found, create it
      ridx = data.length;
      var newRow = [];
      var rowSize = idxMap.length;
      while (rowSize--) newRow.push('');
      data.push(newRow);
    } else {
      eventFound[ridx] = true;
    }
    // Update event in spreadsheet data
    calEventToSheet(calEvent, idxMap, data[ridx]);
  }

  // Remove any data rows not found in the calendar
  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var idx = eventFound.length - 1; idx > 0; idx--) {
    //event doesn't exists and has an event id
    if (!eventFound[idx] && sheetEventIds[idx - 1]) {
      data.splice(idx, 1);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }

  // Save spreadsheet changes
  range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length);
  range.setValues(data);
  if (rowsDeleted > 0) {
    sheet.deleteRows(data.length + 1, rowsDeleted);
  }
}

// Synchronize from spreadsheet to calendar.
function syncToCalendar() {
  console.info('Starting sync to calendar');
  var scriptStart = Date.now();
  // Get calendar and events
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  if (!calendar) {
    errorAlert('Cannot find calendar. Check instructions for set up.');
  }
  var calEvents = calendar.getEvents(beginDate, endDate);
  var calEventIds = calEvents.map(function(val) {return val.getId();});

  // Get spreadsheet and data
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();
  if (data.length < 2) {
    errorAlert('Spreadsheet must have a title row and at least one data row');
    return;
  }

  // Map headers to indices
  var idxMap = createIdxMap(data[0]);
  var idIdx = idxMap.indexOf('id');
  var idRange = range.offset(0, idIdx, data.length, 1);
  var idData = idRange.getValues()

  // Verify header has all required fields
  if (areRequiredFieldsMissing(idxMap)) {
    var reqFieldNames = requiredFields.map(function(x) {return titleRowMap[x];}).join(', ');
    errorAlert('Spreadsheet must have ' + reqFieldNames + ' columns');
    return;
  }

  var keysToAdd = missingFields(idxMap);

  // Loop through spreadsheet rows
  var numAdded = 0;
  var numUpdates = 0;
  var eventsAdded = false;
  for (var ridx = 1; ridx < data.length; ridx++) {
    var sheetEvent = reformatEvent(data[ridx], idxMap, keysToAdd);

    // If enabled, skip rows with blank/invalid start and end times
    if (SKIP_BLANK_ROWS && !(sheetEvent.starttime instanceof Date) &&
        !(sheetEvent.endtime instanceof Date)) {
      continue;
    }

    // Do some error checking first
    if (!sheetEvent.title) {
      errorAlert('must have title', sheetEvent, ridx);
      continue;
    }
    if (!(sheetEvent.starttime instanceof Date)) {
      errorAlert('start time must be a date/time', sheetEvent, ridx);
      continue;
    }
    if (sheetEvent.endtime !== '') {
      if (!(sheetEvent.endtime instanceof Date)) {
        errorAlert('end time must be empty or a date/time', sheetEvent, ridx);
        continue;
      }
      if (sheetEvent.endtime < sheetEvent.starttime) {
        errorAlert('end time must be after start time for event', sheetEvent, ridx);
        continue;
      }
    }

    // Ignore events outside of the begin/end range desired.
    if (sheetEvent.starttime > endDate) {
      continue;
    }
    if (sheetEvent.endtime === '') {
      if (sheetEvent.starttime < beginDate) {
        continue;
      }
    } else {
      if (sheetEvent.endtime < beginDate) {
        continue;
      }
    }

    // Determine if spreadsheet event is already in calendar and matches
    var addEvent = true;
    if (sheetEvent.id) {
      var eventIdx = calEventIds.indexOf(sheetEvent.id);
      if (eventIdx >= 0) {
        calEventIds[eventIdx] = null;  // Prevents removing event below
        addEvent = false;
        var calEvent = calEvents[eventIdx];
        var convertedCalEvent = convertCalEvent(calEvent);
        var eventDiffs = eventDifferences(convertedCalEvent, sheetEvent);
        if (eventDiffs > 0) {
          // When there are only 1 or 2 event differences, it's quicker to
          // update the event. For more event diffs, delete and re-add the event. The one
          // exception is if the event has guests (eventDiffs=99). We don't
          // want to force guests to re-confirm, so go through the slow update
          // process instead.
          if (eventDiffs < 3 && eventDiffs !== EVENT_DIFFS_WITH_GUESTS) {
            numUpdates += updateEvent(calEvent, convertedCalEvent, sheetEvent);
          } else {
            addEvent = true;
            calEventIds[eventIdx] = sheetEvent.id;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    console.info('%d updates, time: %d msecs', numUpdates, Date.now() - scriptStart);

    if (addEvent) {
      var newEvent;
      sheetEvent.sendInvites = SEND_EMAIL_INVITES;
      if (sheetEvent.endtime === '') {
        newEvent = calendar.createAllDayEvent(sheetEvent.title, sheetEvent.starttime, sheetEvent);
      } else {
        newEvent = calendar.createEvent(sheetEvent.title, sheetEvent.starttime, sheetEvent.endtime, sheetEvent);
      }
      // Put event ID back into spreadsheet
      idData[ridx][0] = newEvent.getId();
      eventsAdded = true;

      // Set event color
      if (sheetEvent.color > 0 && sheetEvent.color < 12) {
        newEvent.setColor('' + sheetEvent.color);
      }

      // Throttle updates.
      numAdded++;
      Utilities.sleep(THROTTLE_SLEEP_TIME);
      if (numAdded % 10 === 0) {
        console.info('%d events added, time: %d msecs', numAdded, Date.now() - scriptStart);
      }
    }
    // If the script is getting close to timing out, save the event IDs added so far to avoid lots
    // of duplicate events.
    if ((Date.now() - scriptStart) > MAX_RUN_TIME) {
      idRange.setValues(idData);
    }
  }

  // Save spreadsheet changes
  if (eventsAdded) {
    idRange.setValues(idData);
  }

  // Remove any calendar events not found in the spreadsheet
  var numToRemove = calEventIds.reduce(function(prevVal, curVal) {
    if (curVal !== null) {
      prevVal++;
    }
    return prevVal;
  }, 0);
  if (numToRemove > 0) {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var response = ui.alert('Delete ' + numToRemove + ' calendar event(s) not found in spreadsheet?',
          ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
      var numRemoved = 0;
      calEventIds.forEach(function(id, idx) {
        if (id != null) {
          calEvents[idx].deleteEvent();
          Utilities.sleep(THROTTLE_SLEEP_TIME);
          numRemoved++;
          if (numRemoved % 10 === 0) {
            console.info('%d events removed, time: %d msecs', numRemoved, Date.now() - scriptStart);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

// Set up a trigger to automatically update the calendar when the spreadsheet is
// modified. See the instructions for how to use this.
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('syncToCalendar')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}

// Delete the trigger. Use this to stop automatically updating the calendar.
function deleteTrigger() {
  // Loop over all triggers.
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var idx = 0; idx < allTriggers.length; idx++) {
    if (allTriggers[idx].getHandlerFunction() === 'syncToCalendar') {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[idx]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem for me is that the script keeps prompting the ReferenceError but I can't where else to write a reference i the GAS.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Edit your question. include "your" code and describe any issues you are having with "your" code. Links to other questions are not **YOUR** code.

Comment: @AllanBech, where do you get the error? At which line? Cheers!

Comment: Oh boy! Typo. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReferenceError: calenderId is not defined` error message you are getting is due to the fact that you are declaring `calenderId` instead of `calendarId` and you are using `calendarId` all over your code.

So in order to fix your error you might want to check the line at which you are declaring the variable and declare it with the appropriate name.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I discovered the typo 27/2 after starring myself blind on all other sorts of possible things. Thank You.